# Is the truncated Frobenius norm convex or not?

Tags: normed-spaces, convex-analysis, matrix-norms, singular-values, unitary-matrices

Given a positive integer $k$ and a matrix $X\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. A truncated Frobenius norm of a matrix $X$ is defined by
$$\Vert X \Vert_{k,F} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=k+1}^{m} \sigma_i^2(X)},$$
where $\sigma_i(X)$ are singular values of $X$. I wonder that this norm is convex or not?

For the case Frobenius norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_F$, I can prove it is convex by showing it is a unitarily invariant norm (since $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ is gauge function). But for the case truncated Frobenius norm, I can't use the same technique because $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{k,2}$ is not a gauge function.

Comment: Any norm is positive homogeneous and sub additive, hence convex.

Comment: @copper.hat "Truncated Frobenius norm" is just the name. It is not a norm like Frobenius norm.